Mini Cooper R56 (Trunk opens up automatically)
Mini Cooper R56, (2010) base model, has a very peculiar problem. Whenever the car is started the trunk gets unlocked. Could this be due to leakage of current? How to diagnose?
———————————-
Additional Details
Observation 1: It happens only when i press the start button in the car (not just by inserting the key fob) so this rules out the fact that a key might have been getting pressed during insertion
Observation 2: The hatch continually tries to lock/unclock if i press the start button again and again. So some circuitry is perhaps checking the hatch is locked upon start button being pressed ?
Observation 3: Mini cooper has a functionality of auto door lock when you start driving it at certain speed so perhaps its checking something also during pressing of the start button

The first thing to do is to ensure that something isn't interfering with the opening switch which might only happen at startup.

This makes sense. Any advice how to check for that?

Does this car start with an ignition key? Does the key fob have a button to unlock the trunk? Could you be accidentally pressing the trunk unlock button as you turn the key in the ignition switch?
If the key is reversible, reverse it so you are pressing the back of the key fob with your thumb instead of the front of the fob (where the trunk unlock button is) as you start the car.

The car key fob is electronic, with buttons that opens the trunk. When the car is cranking the trunk doesnt open, only when the car is started, the next thing i hear is trunk opening sound!

Also there is not turning the key. Its with  button start. I speculate that something might be leaking to trigger the opening switch during starting the car
